# Is there an elegant way to use enums in Springs @Query annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to use enums in my `@Query` annotations. Here's an example that's causing an error:

```
@Query("select g from Giveaway g where g.campaign.businessUser.businessId = ?1 "
            + "and where g.status = ?2")
ArrayList<Giveaway> findByStatusAndBusinessId(long businessId, GiveawayStatus status);
```

I've tried just about any solution I could find, including adding `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` above my enums declared in my entities, adding `columnDefinition` in the `@Column` annotation, and I've tried creating a `String` constant containing the above query. I either get this error:

```
The value for annotation attribute Query.value must be a constant expression
```

Or the below stack trace: **(This is the error the above example causes)**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token
```

Everything I've read says Hibernate doesn't really support enums, so I have the following questions:

- Does Hibernate have support for queries containing enums? If so, how would I go about doing this.
- If not, what approach should I take in order to use enums? (Possibly using Strings and checking the Strings against the enums I've declared? This seems very inelegant though.)

**EDIT**

Giveaway object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GIVEAWAYS")
public class Giveaway implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8835490774774467020L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="giveaway_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long giveawayId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="campaign_id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="give_campaign_id"), nullable=false)
    private Campaign campaign;

    @Column(name="status", columnDefinition = "enum('ACTIVE','FINISHED')")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private GiveawayStatus status;
    //Getters/setters below
```

Status enum:

```
public enum GiveawayStatus {
        ACTIVE("Active"), FINISHED("Finished");

        private String giveawayStatus;

        GiveawayStatus(String giveawayStatus) {
            this.giveawayStatus = giveawayStatus;
        }

        public String getGiveawayStatusText() {
            return giveawayStatus;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return giveawayStatus;
        }

        @JsonCreator
        public static GiveawayStatus fromText(String text){
            for(GiveawayStatus s : GiveawayStatus.values()){
                if(s.getGiveawayStatusText().equalsIgnoreCase(text)){
                    return s;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

Complete stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'analyticsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'analyticsService': Error creating bean with name 'IAnalyticsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'giveawayRepository': Error creating bean with name 'giveawayRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.ArrayList com.myproject.app.repositories.GiveawayRepository.findByStatusAndBusinessId(long,com.myproject.app.model.Giveaway$GiveawayStatus)!; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'giveawayRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.ArrayList com.myproject.app.repositories.GiveawayRepository.findByStatusAndBusinessId(long,com.myproject.app.model.Giveaway$GiveawayStatus)!; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'IAnalyticsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'giveawayRepository': Error creating bean with name 'giveawayRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.ArrayList com.myproject.app.repositories.GiveawayRepository.findByStatusAndBusinessId(long,com.myproject.app.model.Giveaway$GiveawayStatus)!; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'giveawayRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.ArrayList com.myproject.app.repositories.GiveawayRepository.findByStatusAndBusinessId(long,com.myproject.app.model.Giveaway$GiveawayStatus)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.myproject.app.main.App.main(App.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'IAnalyticsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'giveawayRepository': Error creating bean with name 'giveawayRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.ArrayList com.myproject.app.repositories.GiveawayRepository.findByStatusAndBusinessId(long,com.myproject.app.model.Giveaway$GiveawayStatus)!; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'giveawayRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.ArrayList com.myproject.app.repositories.GiveawayRepository.findByStatusAndBusinessId(long,com.myproject.app.model.Giveaway$GiveawayStatus)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'giveawayRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.ArrayList com.myproject.app.repositories.GiveawayRepository.findByStatusAndBusinessId(long,com.myproject.app.model.Giveaway$GiveawayStatus)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.ArrayList com.myproject.app.repositories.GiveawayRepository.findByStatusAndBusinessId(long,com.myproject.app.model.Giveaway$GiveawayStatus)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:212) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: where near line 1, column 102 [select g from com.myproject.app.model.Giveaway g where g.campaign.businessUser.businessId = ?1 and where g.status = ?2]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: where near line 1, column 102 [select g from com.myproject.app.model.Giveaway g where g.campaign.businessUser.businessId = ?1 and where g.status = ?2]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The code you posted should work fine, provided Giveaway.status is of type GiveawayStatus. The return type should be List<Giveaway>, though. Post the actual code of the query, the actual code of the entity, and the complete stack trace of the exception you get. I use this on a regular basis with named params instead of numbered params, and it works absolutely fine. Hibernate definitely supports enums; don't know where you read that.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah. I read conflicting answers on a few other Stack Overflow questions. Kinda surprised me because I'd think Hibernate would support enums. I posted what you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
and where g.status = ?2
```

should be

```
and g.status = ?2
```

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. In class MessageManager I have method to call with enum parameter.

```
 List<MessageEntity> messages =
            messageRepository.findAllRsaMessagesOlderThan(
            boundary, DeliveryQuality.RSA.getName());
```

In my MessageRepository are all my queries and I have made query with two params:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT m FROM MessageEntity m 
 WHERE m.deliveredDate < :boundary 
 AND m.messagequalityCode = :messageQualityCode")
 List<MessageEntity> findAllNonRsaMessagesOlderThan(
 @Param("boundary") Date boundary,
 @Param("messageQualityCode") String messageQualityCode);
```